# how to combine asian font and western font as one combined font

Tags: fonts, combine

Is there anyway to combine asian fonts like chinese, korean or japan fonts with english fonts then export as ttf? I heard that Adobe Framemaker can make this but is there any other way without Framemaker?

Comment: You can put all of the glyphs into one font, but the encoding would not match anything else, so you would be only user.

Comment: Why do you believe this to be a better solution than allowing the font engine substitute as required?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Arrived here. A possible answer (the reason I need to do it) to your question is that in some embedded systems you only get one font to use. The particular system I am using supports a unicode font, but you must choose what font to use. It is easiest to use a font with all needed characters.

Answer (score 1):

Font editing software can probably be used to combine glyphs from multiple fonts to produce a new font (where font licences permit)

e.g. [Fontforfge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/), Fontographer, etc

The task may require you to learn more about fonts than you wish to know.

Answer (score 0):

Is seems that you are referring to a Unicode TrueType font?

There are [some fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font#Comparison_of_fonts) (such as [Arial Unicode MS](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?fmid=1081)) that are mapped to the Universal Character Set or Unicode, which allows them to store a glyph for any Unicode / UCS character.  If you create a font that supports this, you will be able to use one font for characters from multiple languages.